# How to add the HopbyHop extension header to Ipv6 header after intercepting packet with libnetfilter_queue

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, ipv6, iptables

i want to modify the ipv6 header by adding a Hop by Hop extension header as a packet next header. Currently, with libnetfilter_queue, i intercept the Ipv6 packet and get its Ipv6 header(to printf src ip, dst ip, packet length, and the next header type).

Now, i try without success to do this task:

if(ipv6 header already contains HopbyHop header){ store this hopbyhop, to use it after }else{ add to this header a stored hopbyhop header}.

can someone help me? Thank in advance.

```
int mycallBack( struct nfq_q_handle *hq, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg, struct nfq_data *nfad, void *data){

  unsigned int len, id, temp_id;
  unsigned char *packet, payload[2048], buf[2048];
  struct ip6_hdr *packet_header; //ipv6 header
  char ip_addr_source[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN], ip_addr_destination[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];


     struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *hp = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfad); //get packet header
      if (hp != NULL) {
        id = ntohl(hp->packet_id);     // Get packet id
        printf("Received packet n°: %d\n", id ); //printf received message
    }

 len = nfq_get_payload(nfad, &packet); //get payload length
 packet_header = (struct ip6_hdr *) packet; // get ip header

 inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &packet_header->ip6_src, ip_addr_source,   INET6_ADDRSTRLEN); //get src ip
 inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &packet_header->ip6_dst, ip_addr_destination, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN); //get dst ip

 printf("Ip source: %s\n", ip_addr_source); //printf @
 printf("Ip destination: %s\n", ip_addr_destination); //printf @


 ////////////////start  Ip hearder modification /////////////////////

if(packet_header->ip6_nxt !=IPPROTO_HOPOPTS){ // IPPROTO_HOPOPTS=0
    printf("Next header is not a HOP by Hop header \n\n");

    //set a set ip6_nxt as a hopbyhop header  and this hopbyhop ->next header as the firstly ip6_nxt ???

    //and set a stored hopbyhop options data to the header ??

    //struct ip6_hbh * hophdr= (struct ip6_hbh *)packet;

}else{

    printf("Next header is already hopbyhop header); 

        //store the hopbyhop and its options data??

    }
      nfq_set_verdict(hq, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);  //resending of packet

return 0;
}
```